# Objective-C giving value on to next View

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, viewcontroller

```
#import "OtherController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
ViewController *viewController;

@interface OtherController ()

@end

@implementation OtherController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];
}

- (IBAction)levelNormal{
    viewController.level = 1;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

I have tried various tips i read on stackoverflow though none of them seemed to work out correctly. I am trying to open a View on Button-click and when the View opens, depending on which button was pressed the View should have a different "level" number. I do not have a NavigationController as far as i'm concerned. I have read different posts about pasting code into the AppDelegate class, though that also did not work out for me. When I debug the pressing of the button, I see that the value is changed but nothing else happens when it tries to change the view.

Here's the ViewController header-file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resumeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *opacityScreen;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mainMenuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer * nst;
@property(nonatomic) int level;
@end
```

Comment: You can only push a view controller if you have a navigation controller...

Comment: Though you mention not using NavigationController, your code depicts that you use navigationcontroller.

Comment: Man, show your log. If you did not embed OtherController in UINavigationController this code will never works.

Comment: Post your crash log then some one help!!

Comment: @ŁukaszTomaszewski how can i embed a UINavigationController in a ViewController? just drag and drop?

Comment: I'm sorry guys i tried so many different things that i didn't realize that it doesn't crash with this code but instead it doesn't do anything at all except changing the level to 1.

Comment: @CuppleKay Embed a UINavigationController in a ViewController : Goto editor ->embed in -> Navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

You have to init `UINavigationController` with root view controller `OtherController`.

Check this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: When i use an embedded NavigationController it changes the view nice and smooth although it doesn't pass the value i want it to anymore.

Comment: Show me your `ViewController` header file.

Comment: I posted it in the question so it's formatted nicer.

Comment: Have you tried `@property (assign,nonatomic) int level;` ? if not it should helps, but i'm to sure. Check it out.

Comment: Well it's not working yet but I figured out i had also used a modal view change and that was really stupid of me. That's why it changed the View but didn't give the value. So when i took it out i just got a "Could not load NIB in bundle", error and the application crashed when trying to change view.

Answer (score 1):

Create UINavigationController object in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and assign a UIViewcontroller object as a rootViewController like below and pass the navObj to window root view.

```
 
viewController = [[ViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navObj];
```

Comment: it just crashes on startup when i try that: 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/D62E59ED-A8CD-4AB4-805F-566E50FB1946/CubeDodger.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

Comment: Load the right nib file in initWithNibName and make sure its the subclass of yourViewController from identity inspector.

Comment: I thought this was correct but please have a look:
    OtherController *viewController = [[OtherController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OtherController" bundle:nil]; //I'm trying to change from otherController to the ViewController on button-click.

Comment: create the  OtherController *viewController = [[OtherController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OtherController" bundle:nil];[self.NavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; within the IBAction of button

Comment: But how is the AppDelegate-File going to know about the viewController? In the code you told me to use I have to set the initWithRootViewController to the said viewController

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)levelNormal
{
    //  viewController.level = 1;



    OtherController *nextobj=[[OtherController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OtherController" bundle:nil];
    nextobj.dictionay_passdata=[your_array_data]; //your data

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextobj animated:YES];

}
```

In your OtherController make a dictionary for store data in OtherController

OtherController.h file

```
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionay_passdata;

}
```

OtherController.m file

```
@implementation OtherController

@synthesize dictionay_passdata; //this is must to write in your code





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionay_passdata);

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: What sort of object type is news supposed to be i don't quite understand.

Comment: Also: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
and: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: I would be voting your answer down though i do not have enough reputation to do so. You tried to help and i appreciate that but you are doing a  bad job